# NextJS: next-translate and yaml loader

Tags: internationalization, yaml, next.js, loader

Is it possible to use [next-translate](https://github.com/vinissimus/next-translate) in combination with a YAML loader? For example, I'd like to use [yaml-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-loader).

I tried it myself with no luck:

```
// file: next.config.js
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate')

module.exports = nextTranslate({
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'es', 'it'],
    defaultLocale: 'en'
  },
  loadLocaleFrom: (lang, ns) =>
    require(`./locales/${lang}/${ns}`).then((m) => m.default),
  webpack: function (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.ya?ml$/,
      use: 'yaml-loader'
    })
    return config
  }
})
```

the previous `next.config.js` configuration throws the following error:

```sh
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:8)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/yaml-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
```

Answer (score 3):

These are the steps to use YAML files instead of JSON files with next-translate:

1. Install [yaml-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-loader):

```
yarn add yaml-loader --dev
```

2. Configure webpack to use yaml-loader. This is my `next.config.js` file:

```js
const nextTranslate = require('next-translate')

module.exports = nextTranslate({
  webpack: function (config) {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.ya?ml$/,
      type: 'json',
      use: 'yaml-loader'
    })
    return config
  }
})
```

2. **Do not use i18n.json.** Instead use `i18n.js`. In my case I have two pages: home (/) and teachers:

```
module.exports = {
  locales: ['en', 'es', 'it'],
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  pages: {
    '*': ['common'],
    '/': ['home'],
    '/teachers': ['teachers']
  },
  // Transform YAML files to JSON objects
  loadLocaleFrom: (lang, ns) => {
    return import(`./locales/${lang}/${ns}.yaml`).then((m) => m.default)
  }
}
```

And that's all! You can now use the human-friendly YAML format, instead of the machine-friendly JSON format.

Answer (score 1):

just like what @Cequiel described, the solution is using webpack config in the next.config.js, but I have compatibility issues while using yaml-loader(0.6.0) together with next.js (12.1.0 which defaultly using webpack 5), I used `js-yaml-loader` (^1.2.2) works well.

Comment: Can you please post your response a comment to @cequiel instead of as answer

Comment: Sure, but stackoverflow limits me from doing that until I got 50 reputations...